# Curl and Divergence definitions - Is this definition mathematically correct?

Tags: calculus, vectors, 3d

I've been using Stewart's *Calculus: Early Transcendentals* in my Calculus class, and one of the definitions of curl offered by the book was $$\text{curl } \vec F = \nabla\times \vec F$$ where $\,\nabla=\left\langle\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\right\rangle$. My question is, why are we allowed to put operations into a vector and then "multiply" them with components of $\vec F$ in that way?

Comment: For your purposes, you should think of it as a mnemonic, not as a definition.

Comment: No, this is simply a shorthand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Ian, this notation is used for memorizing formula rather than as a strict and formal definition of mathematical concept.
Let me quote [article about curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#Usage) from Wikipedia:

> The notation $\,\nabla \times \overrightarrow{F}\,$ has its origins in the similarities to the $3$ dimensional cross product, and *it is useful as a **mnemonic** in Cartesian coordinates* if $\,\nabla\,$ is taken as a vector differential operator del. Such notation involving operators is common in physics and algebra. However, in certain coordinate systems, such as polar-toroidal coordinates (common in plasma physics), using the notation $\,\nabla \times \overrightarrow{F}\,$ will yield an incorrect result.
>
> Expanded in Cartesian coordinates ... , $\,\nabla \times \overrightarrow{F}\,$ is, for $\,\overrightarrow{F}\,$ composed of $\,\left[\begin{array}{3} F_x,& F_y, &F_z\end{array}\right]\,$:
>
> \begin{align}
> \begin{vmatrix} 
> \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\ 
> {\frac{\partial}{\partial x}} & {\frac{\partial}{\partial y}} & {\frac{\partial}{\partial z}} \\
>  F_x & F_y & F_z 
> \end{vmatrix}
> \end{align}
>
> where $\,\mathbf{i},\, \mathbf{j},\,$ and $\,\mathbf{k}\,$ are the unit vectors for the $\,x,\, y,\,$ and $\,z\,$ axes, respectively. This expands as follows:
>
> \begin{align}
> \left(\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y}  - \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial z}\right) \mathbf{i} + \left(\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x}\right) \mathbf{j} + \left(\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}\right) \mathbf{k}
> \end{align}

Comment: If the unit vectors $\vec F$ in the general curvilinear coordinate system are kept in side the differential operations, then actually one can proceed to evaluate straightforward.  So, for example in cylindrical coordinates $$\nabla \times \vec F=\nabla \times \left(\hat \rho F_{\rho}+\hat \phi F_{\phi}+\hat z F_z\right)$$ with $\nabla$ given by the $Del$ operator in cylindrical coordinates.  This is not convenient, but yields the correct result for the curl after painstaking care.